# How to use or in an if statement in lua for watchmaker

Tags: lua

("{ttrash}" == "Thursday Without Recycling" or "Friday Without Recycling") and 100 or 0

Using lua on watchmaker. Above statement controls opacity of image. It should be 100 if ttrash has either value and 0 if ttrash does not equal either value. If I leave out the or and only test one value it works fine. The above evaluates to 100 when ttrash does not equal either value. Can anyone help me get this working?
Thanx

Comment: operation `==` has a higher priority and is executed first... therefore, the value after `or` is always 1.. and what is `"{ttrash}"`?

Answer (score 1):

```
("{ttrash}" == "Thursday Without Recycling" or "Friday Without Recycling") and 100 or 0
```

How is `"{ttrash}"` going to be equal `"Thursday Without Recycling"`?

That's two different strings. They cannot be equal.

Also if you want to check wether something equals one or another thing you need to explicitly use  `a == b or a == c`, not `a == b or c`.

`"{ttrash}" == "Thursday Without Recycling" or "Friday Without Recycling"` resolves to `false or "Friday Without Recycling"` which resolves to `"Friday Without Recycling"`.

As a string is always a true value you'll always get `100` as a result.